To derive the equation of the director circle of a standard ellipse using the tangent lines at any two points on the ellipse
I am currently studying conic sections and have encountered the concept of the director circle (or orthoptic circle) of an ellipse"1". The director circle is defined as the locus of points from which tangents drawn to the ellipse are perpendicular to each other. I am trying to derive the equation of this director circle using tangent lines at two different points"2" and ensuring that the angle between these two tangent lines at their point of intersection is $90^\circ$".3"
I have derived the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point of intersection of the tangent lines and ensured that the product of their slopes is $-1$.
However, I am not sure how to proceed further to find the equation of the director circle.
Can someone help me understand the final steps to derive the director circle of the ellipse?
When I use the slope of straight line segment joining point of contacts of tangent to ellipse, by finding the equation of this straight line using point of intersection of tangent lines= chord of contact, the director circle comes to be a straight line.

Another possible derivation is as follows.
Consider the parametric equation of the line passing through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ with direction vector
$(\alpha,\beta)$
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ccc}
x(t) &=& x_0 + t\alpha \\
y(t) &=& y_0 + t\beta
\end{array}
\right.
$$
This line is tangent to the ellipse
if the quadratic polynomial $P(t)$ has equal roots
$$
P(t):
=  \frac{x^2(t)}{a^2}+\frac{y^2(t)}{b^2}-1
= \left[\frac{\alpha^2}{a^2}+\frac{\beta^2}{b^2} \right]t^2
+2\left[\frac{\alpha x_0}{a^2}+\frac{\beta y_0}{b^2} \right]t
+ \left[\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_0^2}{b^2}-1 \right]
$$
The discriminant is thus zero
$$
\Delta_1:=
\left[\frac{\alpha x_0}{a^2}+\frac{\beta y_0}{b^2} \right]^2
- 
\left[\frac{\alpha^2}{a^2}+\frac{\beta^2}{b^2} \right]
\left[\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_0^2}{b^2}-1 \right]
=
0
$$
The orthogonal line with direction vector $(-\beta,\alpha)$
is tangent to the ellipse if the (orthogonal) discriminant is also null
$$
\Delta_2:=
\left[\frac{-\beta x_0}{a^2}+\frac{\alpha y_0}{b^2} \right]^2
- 
\left[\frac{\beta^2}{a^2}+\frac{\alpha^2}{b^2} \right]
\left[\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_0^2}{b^2}-1 \right]
=
0
$$
Summing the two equations
$$
(\alpha^2+\beta^2)
\left\lbrace
\left[\frac{x_0^2}{a^4}+\frac{y_0^2}{b^4} \right]
- 
\left[\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2} \right]
\left[\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_0^2}{b^2}-1 \right]
\right\rbrace
=
0
$$
This implies
$$
\frac{x_0^2}{a^4}+\frac{y_0^2}{b^4}
=
\left[\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2} \right]
\left[\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}+\frac{y_0^2}{b^2}-1 \right]
$$
or after simplification
$$
\frac{x_0^2+y_0^2}{a^2b^2}
=
\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}
$$
and thus
$$
x_0^2+y_0^2 = a^2+b^2
$$

Steph, "But Please Can You Derive It By The Method I Am Asking?"
